# Perl MySQL - Insert Query

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get this method to work but I'm getting a syntax error output on my console.

```
method insert($table, \@columns, \@values) {
   return if (!$table && !scalar(@columns) && !scalar(@values));
   my $fields = join(", ", @columns);
   my $statement = $self->{mysql}->prepare("INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES " . join(", ", ("?") x scalar(@columns)));
   $statement->execute(@values);
   return $statement->{mysql_insertid};
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't VALUES be followed by parentheses? `VALUES (?, ?, ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VALUES should be followed by parentheses:

```
VALUES(?, ?, ?)
```

i.e.

```
"VALUES (" . join(', ', ('?') x @columns) . ')'
```